# PowerQuery SSIS Connection Manager "Exchange" failed

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, powerquery, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I would like to make an "Exchange" connection with PowerQuery Source within SSIS (with my office365 email).
When I test the connection with my credentials, I get the below error:

[image: Screenshot power query connection manager]

"We were unable to use the provided Exchange credential to connect. (Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ProviderCommon)"

I have also created an app password with office environment.
Unfortunately, this also not works.
Does anybody know if this is even possible and how to fix it?

Comment: Basic authentication and app passwords have been depreciated in EWS so if your trying to use the Exchange Connector that won't work. There should be an Exchange Online connector that support oauth that you should use when connecting to Office365